# angular directive variable not available in parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently stuck on hopefully a simple problem:

I have a controller.js

```
app.controller('WizardCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.send = function() {
    console.log($scope.isPasswordChanged)
  }
});
```

My view.html

```
isPasswordChanged: {{ isPasswordChanged }} <br>
<update-password-field is-changed="isPasswordChanged"></update-password-field>
<button ng-click="send()"></button>
```

My directive.js

```
app.directive('updatePasswordField', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      isChanged: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "password-field-directive.html",
    link: function (scope) {
        // some magic to set isChanged value to true of false 
    }
  }
});
```

So in my view.html I can see the changes of "isPasswordChanged", to it is somehow in my $scope, but if I console.log($scope) the "isPasswordChanged" is not present.

Why and how to make it present?

Comment: where did u put the `console.log($scope) `?

Comment: when you call `send` function? can you provide working sample?

Comment: @K.Toress in my send() function, I updated my view.html

Comment: @Grundy I updates my view.html

Comment: I think @Craig has the answer

Comment: @K.Toress, i think answer is your comment to Craig's answer :-D

Comment: @K.Toress my code already has $scope in my controller :(

Comment: @Fribu you still need the `['$scope', ...` part in your controller's declaration. Look closely at my answer.

Comment: @Fribu, can you provide working plunkr? and sample `"password-field-directive.html"` and `// some magic to set isChanged value to true of false`?

Comment: what will you get on `console.log($scope.isPasswordChanged);` is it `undefined`?

Comment: @K.Toress yes it is undefined, like the variable not exists. I added a solution to this problem (in my case)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to include the `$scope` in your controller's function(). In other words:

```
app.controller('WizardCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

Otherwise I don't believe it will work.

Comment: I think it should be `app.controller('WizardCtrl', function ($scope) {..` ? isn't it?

Comment: @K.Toress Ok I've fixed it.

Comment: @Craig regarding to thes topic, I can inject $scope in my directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311102/filter-scope-error-unknown-provider-scopeprovider-scope-transformsens

Comment: @Craig sorry, it was only an example, but my real code contains $scope in my controller. I just updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it is a problem with probably my structure.

I changed

```
is-confirmed="isPasswordConfirmed"
```

to

```
is-confirmed="ui.isPasswordConfirmed"
```

"ui" is an empty object I defined in my $scope.

And its working. I tried a stand alone example

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/bkMZTEWgkrmVfxqiYCcB?p=preview
```

But it is working without this changes, it also might be a mismatch with angular version.